# embedding python interpreter fails with lots of linker errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew, cpython, python-embedding

After building cpython:

```
./configure --with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl) --enable-optimizations --prefix=/path/to/build
make
make install
```

I want to compile an application with an embedded python interpreter. Compiling the pybind11 units tests:

```
cmake .. -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/build/python3.9 -DDOWNLOAD_CATCH=ON
make --build .
```

fails with lots of linker errors when linking the embed tests.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ASN1_OBJECT_free", referenced from:
      __ssl_txt2obj_impl in libpython3.9.a(_ssl.o)
      __ssl_nid2obj_impl in libpython3.9.a(_ssl.o)
  "_ASN1_OCTET_STRING_free", referenced from:
      __ssl_configure_hostname in libpython3.9.a(_ssl.o)
  "_ASN1_STRING_get0_data", referenced from:
      __ssl_configure_hostname in libpython3.9.a(_ssl.o)
      __get_peer_alt_names in libpython3.9.a(_ssl.o)
  "_putwin", referenced from:
      __curses_window_putwin in libpython3.9.a(_cursesmodule.o)
  "_qiflush", referenced from:
      __curses_qiflush_impl in libpython3.9.a(_cursesmodule.o)
```

**edit**
The list of errors is quite long complaining about many objects: readline.o, statement.o, ...

Any clues what I am missing?

Comment: They certainly look like SSL errors. What's the output of `brew --prefix openssl`?

Comment: `/usr/local/opt/openssl@3`
but it is not limited to SSL, I just cropped the long list of linking errors, I'll edit the original question to be more clear

Comment: Do you get any errors from `configure`? It should usually fail if something is missing.

Comment: I don't see anything being wrong: https://pastebin.com/X2YwmexV
The build and link works fine, just using the library fails